# Bash - Echo a variable using another variable (?)

Tags: bash

Thank you very much in advance for helping!

I have this variables:

```
scene1=lounge
scene2=bedroom
scene3=bathroom
```

What I want to do is a loop, and for every file in a particular folder, echo the variable scene#

```
order=1
for f in $(find $dest_scenes/*.xml -maxdepth 0 )
do
    scene_name=scene$order #scene1, scene2, scene3
    echo $scene_name
done
order=$(expr $order + 1)
```

Output:

```
scene1
scene2
scene3
```

What I would like to:

```
lounge
bedroom
bathroom
```

I don't want to get $scene_name, I want to got $($scene_name) if you know what I mean...

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's called variable interpolation. In your case, you could do:

```
echo ${!scene_name}
```

See [How do I use a variable within a variable](http://wiki.debian.org/ShellTricks#How_do_I_use_a_variable_within_a_variable_.28variable_interpolation.29_in_bash.3F) for more variations.